# JWT authentication and authorization with Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

Can anybody explain me how to do user login authentication and authorization using React (or any frontend framework) as the entry point and then using JWT authentication (spring boot) and the token remains valid  for all the rest api calls made by the user . Also if the user closes the browser (like gmail or facebook) the token remains valid and next time if the same user logs in he should directly redirect to the home page.﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we understand, we need to know exactly what is the difference in authentication between traditional HTTP-based web sites and mobile devices.

The `Session` or `Token` main differences is `Session` is based on client browser environment.

Browser agent will automatic include the `Cookie` into request header. Therefore backend can extract the `Session ID`, Once we have the session ID, we can get the information of the current requester.

When we are out of the browser environment, every API request must be given an authentication token by ourselves because the HTTP protocol is stateless, so we need to specify a token to allow the server to identify who we are.

`JWT` biggest advantage is unforgeable, and can carry some non-sensitive information. Because it's unforgeable, every back-end application can feel comfortable using the data inside (such as user IDs), which is very helpful for building distributed authentication. Although `JWT` have `expired time`, we need the state of the persistent token once we need to revoke the token.

This answer may not be an exact solution, but it will help you choose the right technology to be compatible with all platforms for authentication.

Comment: This was great. Nice explanation. Thank you so much.